# Substituting the instance of a character, except the first, in a input string

Tags: python, string, loops

Since strings in python are immutable, i tried this workaround: I first broke the string in its character components, putting them inside a list. Then i proceeded by looping inside this list and substituting the second occurrence of the character i wanted to modify into the target character.
The last part was of course to re-build the string from the new list thus obtained.

```
def modify():
  space = " "
  # This is the input part
  varstr = input("Insert a string to modify:\n> ")
  if space in varstr:
     print("Please insert a string without space")
     modify()
  varchar = input("Insert a SINGLE character to modify in $:\n> ")
  if len(varstr) > 1:
    print("Please insert a single character, without spaces")
  counter = 0
  liststr = []
  stringout = ""
  #Creating the list composed by the characters of the string
  for i in varstr:                  
      liststr.append(i)
  #Looping through the string and substituting the character from its second occurence
  for j in range(len(liststr)):
      if counter >= 1 and liststr[j] == varchar:
      liststr[j] = "$"
  elif counter == 0 and liststr[j] == varchar:
      counter += 1
  for k in liststr:
      stringout += k 
  return stringout
```

My question is: can this code be made a bit more tidy?

Edit: The Sample Input may be "Google" and the character "o". The sample output would be then

```
Go$gle
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand with sample input and sample output. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: This will replace every occurrence starting from the second. Is that desired?

Comment: I added the sample input and output at the end of the post.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes! That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
char = "a"
stri = "santaclaus"
char.join("$".join(s.split(char)) for s in stri.split(char, 1))
# 'sant$cl$us'
```

This splits on the first `char` occurrence, and joins the tokens back together after "`char.split`ting and `'$'.join`ing" them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def modify():
    while True:  
        varstr = input("Insert a string to modify:\n> ")
        if ' ' in varstr:
            print("Please insert a string without space")
        else:
            break
    while True:
        varchar = input("Insert a SINGLE character to modify in $:\n> ")
        if len(varchar) > 1:
            print("Please insert a single character, without spaces")
        else:
            break
    return varstr[0] + varstr[1:].replace(varchar, '$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def modify():
    while True:
        varstr = input("Insert a string to modify:\n> ")
        if len(varstr) > 0 and ' ' not in varstr:
            break
        print("Please insert a string without space")
    while True:
        varchar = input("Insert a SINGLE character to modify in $:\n> ")
        if len(varchar) == 1 and varchar != ' ':
            break
        print("Please insert a single character, without spaces")
    first = varstr.find(varchar) + 1
    varstr = varstr[:first] + varstr[first:].replace(varchar, "$")
    return varstr
```

---

A few points about the question code:

- You can use a while loop as shown, instead of recursion, to repeat the input. If you really want to use recursion you have to add a `return` after the `modify()` call.
- If you want to convert a string to list of characters, you can use `strlist = list(varstr)`. Then you can mutate, and return to string using `''.join(strlist)`